# LoadRunner COM/DCOM and Trapping Sub

Tags: com, loadrunner

When first using the protocoll advisor on my app I get reccomended to use the COM/DCOM protocoll for recoring the LoadRunnser VUser script. I am doing so but when starting to record I get a pop-up mesasage saying:

"Trapping Sub Process"
"You must be administrator to record sub processes, recording only main process"

What does this indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have access to the full source code of the application you are recording and have access to the developers of the application to help you set the filters for COM/DCOM then you should avoid it as if it was ebola-laced bubonic plague.    Never use it on a commercial application, such as a browser, where you have no access to the source code.

Also, your error message notes a potential issue with your rights on your host.   The installation requirements note that administrative access is the recommended model for use of the LoadRunner tools.    The error message as noted seems to imply that you may not have administrative access to your host.